# Картинка и заголовки в качестве логотипа, bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать так, чтобы при смене изображений менялась картинка и заголовок (вместе они составляют логотип):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Храм св. прп. Сергия Радонежского</title>

  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-8 ">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="/" class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwT_QRo3-Rtjno40A4etZJL6ThvnEnHBHajjE4AWAE-n--HohoxFpXA9Q" alt="Св. прп. Сергий Радонежский">
                </a>
                <div id="logo" class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <a href="/">
                    <h6>Русская православная церковь Московский патриархат <br /> Официальный сайт
                    </h6>
                    <h3>Храм св. прп. Сергия Радонежского</h3>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">СЕГОДНЯ:</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p> 27 сентября 2017 г. ( 14 сентября ст.ст.), среда. Седмица 17-я по Пятидесятнице. Строгий пост. Пища с растительным маслом. Воздвижение Честного и Животворящего Креста Господня. Преставление свт. Иоанна Златоуста. Леснинской иконы Божией
                Матери. Утр. - Ин., 42 зач. (от полу́), XII, 28-36. Лит. - 1 Кор., 125 зач., I, 18-24. Ин., 60 зач., XIX, 6-11, 13-20, 25-28, 30-35.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Правильная ли разметка, и как надо сделать так, чтобы при любых размерах экрана картинка и название сайта адаптировалось и отображалось в одну строчку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы расположить заголовок рядом с картинкой вы используете класс `navbar-nav`  —  это плохое решение: он настроен на показ элементов в ряд только на большом разрешении. Выкините этот класс и настройте через CSS `float:left` у картинки:

```css
#logoimage {
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 80px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-xs-8">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a href="/" id="logoimage">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwT_QRo3-Rtjno40A4etZJL6ThvnEnHBHajjE4AWAE-n--HohoxFpXA9Q" alt="Св. прп. Сергий Радонежский">
              </a>
              <div id="logo">
                <a href="/">
                  <h6>Русская православная церковь Московский патриархат <br /> Официальный сайт
                  </h6>
                  <h3>Храм св. прп. Сергия Радонежского</h3>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 ">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">СЕГОДНЯ:</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p> 27 сентября 2017 г. ( 14 сентября ст.ст.), среда. Седмица 17-я по Пятидесятнице. Строгий пост. Пища с растительным маслом. Воздвижение Честного и Животворящего Креста Господня. Преставление свт. Иоанна Златоуста. Леснинской иконы Божией Матери.
              Утр. - Ин., 42 зач. (от полу́), XII, 28-36. Лит. - 1 Кор., 125 зач., I, 18-24. Ин., 60 зач., XIX, 6-11, 13-20, 25-28, 30-35.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Так-же проследите, что вы используете не только классы "`col-md-X`" но и "`col-xs-X`". `md` - означает средний размер экрана, а нужны еще `xs` - мобильный, `sm` - планшет. [Изучите этот вопрос](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я читала справочник по плагину. Кажется, там неправильно указаны сетки. Если md=12, то xs=36, а sm=6 .  Да, я до-сих пор не понимаю.Example: Mobile and desktop (1 пример не работает у меня, я поставила в итоге:`<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-24 col-md-8 "></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 "></div></div>`)

Comment: @Flambo нет, сетки везде одинаковые - 12 частей, разница только в разрешении экрана. На мобильном действует xs; на планшете действует xs и sm, но sm в приоритете;  на среднем экране xs, sm, md, md в приоритете; на большом - в приоритете lg. Таким образом надо везде указать xs, остальное по необходимости. И там везде 12 частей, col-xs-24 быть не может

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: спасибо огромное! Но я не понимаю, откуда берется `.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4
Copy
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>` , `md` в сумме дает 12.  Для 1-го , вложенного в `.row` `div`  планшет `sm` будет отображаться половинка `div`, а для мобилы полный `div`. И что больше (мобила или планшет), и как получаются эти цифры `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 `?

Comment: @Flambo `col-xs-12 col-sm-6` означает, что на среднем разрешении блок будет занимать половину ширины, а на мобильнике всю ширину, и блок, находящийся рядом с ним, съедет на новую строчку

Comment: спасибо, на основе чего , по какой формуле вычисляются `xs-12, sm-6`, методом подбора, что-то в это слабо верится.

Comment: http://bloggood.ru/bootstrap/uroki-bootstrap-3-0-dlya-nachinayushhix-4-j-urok-setka.html/
Кому тоже не понятна разметка. Вот тут написано нормально-)))

Comment: я понимаю так, нужно иметь под рукой psd сайта и исходник сетки бутстрап для 1170px, 970px, 750px
и накладывать исходник на сетку бутстрапа.